# Save multiple images fetched in Cakephp

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp, jqplot

I am trying to save multiple images on the server. Lets start from the beginning:

```
//I use this function for testing
function testSave(){
    $this->_renderChart(156);
}

//This function takes chart_id as a parameter to render a proper chart.
function _renderChart($chart_id = null){
    if(!$chart_id)
        return false;
    $chartFilterList = $this->getChartFilterListFromId($chart_id);
    $this->loadChartFromId($chart_id, $chartFilterList);
    $this->layout = 'analytics\chart_one.ctp';
}
```

The above function's view contains all the necessary scripts to render the chart. This is the part that is translating the rendered chart into base64string and saves it:

```
//../views/layouts/analytics/chart_one.ctp
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        saveChartAsImage('#chart1');
    });
</script>
```

And the above function's body:

```
function saveChartAsImage(div){
    var base64string = $(div).jqplotToImageStr();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'saveImage',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data:"data=" + base64string
    });
}
```

}

This is not even close to be working. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: The functions you list, are they server-side? Or do you initialize the jqplot jQuery plugin with them, and you are looking for a solution how to save these canvas elements to an image?

Comment: @axel.michel question updated

Comment: Could you clearify what exactly does not work? When you do it on client side, for example: var img = $('yourSelector').jqplotToImage(0,0); if (img) {window.open(img.toDataURL("image/png"));} do you get a valid image then? What exactly do you do when saving the image?

Answer (score 0):

If these functions are controller actions you can use `$this->response->body()` in controller's `afterFilter()` callback to get the response content and save it to file. If these are helper functions you can get the content in `afterLayout()` or `afterRender()` callbacks of the helper using `$this->_View->Blocks->get('content');`

Answer (score 0):

I advise creating a behavior, and add the action **beforeValidate()**;
After that make the conditions necessary to invoke the specific actions (listed in your question).

Example:

```
app/Model/Behavior/ChartBehavior.php
class ChartBehavior extends ModelBehavior {

// if necessary, create a setup action
public function setup(Model $Model, $settings = array()) {  }

public function upload(Model $Model) {
    // use the $Model->data to see all information from your form
    debug($Mode->data);

    // now call your functions below to upload
}

public function line_chart($chart_id = null){
    //magic...
}

public function bar_chart($chart_id = null){
    //magic...
}

public function pie_chart($chart_id = null){
    //magic...
}
```

I hope it helps you.